# Unable to get images to load using dotnet angular webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, .net-core, urlloader

I followed the ["Building Single Page Applications on ASP.NET Core with JavaScriptServices"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/) blog post. And from that I was able to create a new **Angular2** template running on **ASp.NET Core**. That app works great and uses webpack (didn't know that was possible).

```
dotnet new angular    
dotnet restore    
npm install    
dotnet run
```

I am trying to figure out how I can add an `img` to an angular template and supply it a known `src` url - and it work. For the life of me, I cannot figure this out. Here is the `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js', '.ts' ] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: '/dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'] },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot-client.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });

    // Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot-server.ts' },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./ClientApp/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
                sourceType: 'commonjs2',
                name: './vendor'
            })
        ],
        output: {
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
        },
        target: 'node',
        devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
};
```

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'example',
    template: `<img src='dist/myimg.png' />`
})
export class ExampleComponent { }
```

**Update**

I found this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41426787/2410379) which helps clear up a few things. Now the issues is that I have a need to get images dynamically.

Steve answered this question pertaining to his templates for **Angular2** + **ASP.NET Core**. I want to know how to do this dynamically, instead of statically. I want to use **Angular2** binding and get an image name from the server and then bind that to the `img src`. Any ideas on how to do this would be appreciated. It seems like webpack requires it to be known ahead of time so that it is bundled

Comment: your image path looks odd. ~ will not be replaced as the application root - you are not serving an ASP.net page.

Comment: After some searching [it was suggested](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/193#issuecomment-206510064) to use that to tell `webpack` how to handle it. If I have it has `<img src='dist/myimg.png' />` I get a errors stating that it cannot find the module for the image, which is crazy talk.

Answer (score 0):

put image in wwwroot/dist and then...

```
template: "<img src='dist/myimg.png' />"
```

Comment: This only works for static images, as they are then bundled via `webpack`. I want to know how to get images via **Angular2** binding that are dynamic.