# Load static images on ASP.NET Core + Angular 2 template for Visual Studio

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a qiute a lot of images that are shared across Angular components/pages, so I've created an `images` folder inside the `wwwroot` folder.

But whenever I try to reference an image from  `any.component.html` I get the following error:

> Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module
>   "../build/images/logo/logo-light.png"

[image]

I tried to change the path from `../build` to `build`, `~/build` etc. But that doesn't do the trick.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Perhaps its a double-quotes vs single-quotes issue. That error message looks awfully familiar...

Comment: Could you try /build or /build/images or /images  or images?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Image path on ASP.NET Core + Angular 2 template for Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426787/set-image-path-on-asp-net-core-angular-2-template-for-visual-studio)